# Commonly used Enterprise proxy server

Tags: proxy

What are the commonly used proxy servers by most of the companies/enterprises.
Some Examples: Squid, Wingate etc.

I need to know the top 8-10 such commonly used proxy.

Thanks,

Vinay

Comment: cant really provide you with a top 10 list or anything, but at my workplace we use haproxy - http://haproxy.1wt.eu/

Comment: my personal favorite is Dante (SOCKS5). The documentation for it is awful, but it`s a great piece of software once you understand it.